# Prevent auto launch after install of electron app

Tags: electron, electron-forge, squirrel.windows

I am using the Electron framework to build an app on windows. I use electron-forge to make the setup.exe.

My problem is the following at the end of the install, the app is automatically started. I would like to prevent this behavior, but I can not find a solution anywhere.

To clarify, I am not talking about the opening of the app during the install that can be prevented by

```
if (require('electron-squirrel-startup')) {
  app.quit();
}
```